# Changing Keyboard Layout on Windows Mobile

Tags: c++, windows-mobile

In the application there is a dialog where only numeric string entries are valid. Therefore I would like to set the numeric keyboard layout.

Does anyone know how to simulate key press on the keyboard or any other method to change the keyboard layout?

Thanks!

Comment: The result can be achieved by sending a message with the following parameters:

SendMessage(EM_SETINPUTMODE, 0, EIM_NUMBERS);

Comment: Are you running smartphone? What device are you using?

Comment: It's a Pocket PC (HTC TyTN II)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to.

Just like full windows, you can set the edit control to be numeric input only.  You can either do it [manually](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761655(VS.85).aspx) or in the dialog editor in the properites for the edit control.

The SIP should automatically display the numeric keyboard when the numeric only edit control goes into focus.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the InputModeEditor:

```
InputModeEditor.SetInputMode(textBox1,InputMode.Numeric);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way to do this (edit: this is referring to the SIP in non-smartphone Windows Mobile, so I'm not sure it's relevant to your question), and it does involve simulating a mouse click on the 123 button.  This is only half the problem, however, since you also need to know whether the keyboard is already in numeric mode or not.  The way to do this is to peek a pixel near the upper left corner of the keypad - if you look at how the 123 button works, you'll see that it's system text on windows background, and then inverted in numeric mode (so the pixel will be the system text color only when in numeric mode).  There's one more bit of weirdness you have to do to guarantee it will work on all devices (you have to draw a pixel on the keyboard, too).

Lucky for you, I have an easy-to-use code sample that does all this.  Unlucky for you, it's in C#, but I think it should at least point you in the right direction.